# git clone does not work in (sshfs) mapped drive in windows

Tags: git, windows-10, sshfs

We have mounted `Z:` drive using sshfs in Windows 10. We are able to clone our repo in `C:` drive but not on the mapped network drive `Z:`

Error:

```
$ git clone https://<repo>.git
    Cloning into ...
    fatal: Invalid path '//sshfs/user@server1/../../test1/site_playbook': 
    No such file or directory
```

Comment: I've found I can usually get around a similar issue by cloning into C then moving to another drive, after which pulling and pushing is ok.